# glxinfo Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, opengl, mesa

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server with 3 Quadro P5000. I downloaded `LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER` with version number `390.77`
I installed several mesa packages

```
$ apt list --installed | grep mesa
libegl1-mesa/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgl1-mesa-dev/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgl1-mesa-dri/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libgl1-mesa-glx/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
libglapi-mesa/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libglu1-mesa/xenial,now 9.0.0-2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libglu1-mesa-dev/xenial,now 9.0.0-2.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libwayland-egl1-mesa/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mesa-common-dev/xenial-updates,now 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed]
mesa-utils/xenial,now 8.3.0-1 amd64 [installed]
mesa-vdpau-drivers/now 17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1]
```

Then I tried

```
$ glxgears
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

I tried optirun

```
$ optirun -d $DISPLAY glxgears
[VGL] NOTICE: Automatically setting VGL_CLIENT environment variable to
[VGL]    138.25.150.116, the IP address of your SSH client.
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

I use ssh to do all this. VirtualGL is a helpful tool to do this, but I failed with glxgears and glxinfo, I think it might be nvidia driver or config problem. My display management service is lightdm, so there is no xorg.log. However, I didn't find useful lightdm log in `/var/log/lightdm`.

It looks like a common problem but all solution online are tried without progress. Does anyone knows how to debug it ?